# Python Plotly express two bubble markers on the same scatter_geo?

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-express

Hi is it possible to have two different bubble types representing two different values from the same dataframe?

Currently my code is as follows:

```
covid = pd.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')

fig = px.scatter_geo(covid, locations="Country/Region", locationmode="country names",animation_frame = "ObservationDate", hover_name = "Country/Region", size = "Confirmed", size_max = 100, projection= "natural earth")
```

Which produces the following output:
[Map output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBDUW.png)

Is it possible to get it to show two different bubbles, one for confirmed cases and another for tweets? The data frame I'm working with is shown here:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uTVH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! You can freely add another dataset from `px.scatter_geo()` on an *existing* `px.scatter_geo()` using:

```
fig=px.scatter_geo()
fig.add_traces(fig1._data)
fig.add_traces(fig2._data)
```

Where `fig1._data` comes from a setup similar to yours in:

```
fig = px.scatter_geo(covid, locations="Country/Region", locationmode="country names",animation_frame = "ObservationDate", hover_name = "Country/Region", size = "Confirmed", size_max = 100, projection= "natural earth")
```

Since you haven't provided a dataset I'll use `px.data.gapminder()` and use the columns `pop` and `gdpPercap`, where the color of the latter is set to `'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'` which is a transparent red:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig1 = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                     size="pop", # size of markers, "pop" is one of the columns of gapminder
                     )
fig2 = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                     size="gdpPercap", # size of markers, "pop" is one of the columns of gapminder
                     )

# fig1.add_traces(fig2._data)
# fig1.show()
fig=px.scatter_geo()
fig.add_traces(fig1._data)
fig.add_traces(fig2._data)

fig.data[1].marker.color = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'

f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Please let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works to plot both bubbles. doing it this was `fig1.add_traces(fig2._data)

fig1.write_html('second.html', auto_open = True)` This works to shown the animation of the cases but the tweets remain static. The further question to this is can both case and tweet bubbles are animated on the same plot?

Comment: @Rob13563656 I'd be happy to try and find solutions to further questions as well, but please ask those as *new* questions. Otherwise these posts get really messy very quickly. You can refer to this question and ask about animations in a new post. If my suggestion to *this* question was useful, please consider leaving an upvote and mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: No worries asked a new question, Upvoted and marked as accepted :)